# LongListSelector in Windows Phone 8

Tags: sql-server, windows-phone-8

I am currently encountring issues with the LongLisSelector in Windows Phone 8.

I would like to display a List, PROBLEM being an entity of my SQL database that I retrieved thanks to WCF Dataservices. I wrote this function to return the elements of PROBLEM as an ObservableCollection:

```
private ObservableCollection<PROBLEM> CreateProblemGroups()
{
     ObservableCollection<PROBLEM> listpb = new ObservableCollection<PROBLEM>();
     var l = (from lp in problems where lp.IdProblem == lp.IdMainProblem select lp).FirstOrDefault();
     listpb.Add(l);
     return listpb;
}
```

Then, in the load event of my Long List Selector (called ListProblems), I simply bind my previous ObservableCOllection to the item source of my ListProblems:

```
private void ListProblems_Loaded(object sender, LoadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
     ObservableCollection<PROBLEM> data = new ObservableCollection<PROBLEM>();
     data = CreateProblemGroups();
     LongListProblems.ItemsSource = data;
}
```

The code is compiled with no error and the application runs fine, but nothing is displayed in the end.

I also tried to test this tutorial from MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj244365(v=vs.105).aspx) but I am always getting an XAML Parse Exception, stating: "Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key AddrBookJumpListStyle [Line: 52 Position: 17]"

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Could you also post your XAML?  Also, the "key" in the AddrBookJumpListStyle is used to sort each element in your list alphabetically, where you are receiving this error.  Try removing the JumpListStyle from your tutorial and see if that helps.  Also, what does the CreateProblemGroups method do?  Maybe this is where it is hanging up.

Comment: <Grid>
     <phone:LongListSelector
          x:Name="AddrBook"
          JumpListStyle="{StaticResource AddrBookJumpListStyle}"
          Background="Transparent"
          GroupHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource AddrBookGroupHeaderTemplate}"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AddrBookItemTemplate}"
          LayoutMode="List"
          IsGroupingEnabled="true"
          HideEmptyGroups ="true"/>
</Grid>

Comment: <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="AddrBookItemTemplate">
            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold"  Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Address}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Phone}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

Comment: <DataTemplate x:Key="AddrBookGroupHeaderTemplate">
            <Border Background="Transparent" Padding="5">
                <Border Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" BorderThickness="2" Width="62" 
         Height="62" Margin="0,0,18,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" FontSize="48" Padding="6" 
            FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiLight}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

Comment: </Border>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>

        <phone:JumpListItemBackgroundConverter x:Key="BackgroundConverter"/>
        <phone:JumpListItemForegroundConverter x:Key="ForegroundConverter"/>

Comment: </Border>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>

        <phone:JumpListItemBackgroundConverter x:Key="BackgroundConverter"/>
        <phone:JumpListItemForegroundConverter x:Key="ForegroundConverter"/>
        <Style x:Key="AddrBookJumpListStyle" TargetType="phone:LongListSelector">
            <Setter Property="GridCellSize"  Value="113,113"/>
            <Setter Property="LayoutMode" Value="Grid" />

Comment: <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BackgroundConverter}}" Width="113" Height="113" Margin="6" >
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}" FontSize="48" Padding="6" 
               Foreground="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ForegroundConverter}}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>

Comment: </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>